# rails nested form unable to find method of child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-forms

I have 2 models servicio and caja.

Servicio, has_many :caja
Caja, belongs_to :servicio

but i can't find the method servicio.cajas for some reason, i'm able to find servicio.caja tho. Am i missing anything? Do i need to provide more info?

Message from logs

```
 00:04:57 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `cajas' for #<Servicio:0x00000004ae55e8>):
1: <%= form_for([@servicio, @servicio.cajas.new]) do |f| %>
2:   <div class="field">
3:     <%= f.label :tipo_id %><br />
4:     <%= f.text_field :tipo_id %>
app/views/cajas/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_cajas_new_html_erb___4360865893086628466_37227020_2289718708193017139'
app/views/servicios/show.html.erb:68:in `_app_views_servicios_show_html_erb__559030007672389687_39240460_2289718708193017139'
app/controllers/servicios_controller.rb:18:in `show'
```

Comment: no need to answer this question, I found the root, i will add the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. I had an error while defining the has_many :cajas, i previously had has_many :caja.